# In sails use a "basemodel", derive from that and use baseclass functions?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, lodash, dry, derived-class

To improve our program and reduce code redundancy, we wish to create some inheritance inside the models..

Now take a typical `User` model, it has a name and password field as "baseclass" and several subclasses can improve upon this depending in the specific application's needs.

So a baseuser would look like:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
  },
  beforeCreate: async function(user, cb) {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    user.password = hash;
    cb();
  },
}
```

This bare class doesn't correspond to any database table in its own. Now in derived class from this, `VerifyableUser` (a model for users that must have verification links), there are a few extra fields, one which is a verify url.

Now to "extend" classes lodash' `_.merge` function is used, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538630/how-can-i-add-an-instance-method-to-all-models-in-sails-js) .

```
const BaseUser = require("../../BaseUser.js");
module.exports = _.merge({}, BaseUser, {
  attributes: {
    verify_key: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: async function(user, cb) {
    user.verify_key = 'helloworld'; //crypto used to generate...
    cb();
  }
};
```

Now the problem should be obvious, the derived class' `beforeCreate` overwrites the original `beforeCreate`: in a normal OO environment this isn't a big problem either, as I could just call `Base.beforeCreate()` or something similar. 
However can something be done using lodash' merge? Or should I use another way to extend objects? (Or do I really have to repeat myself and retype the `beforeCreate`?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or something similar:

```
 // VerifyableUser
 async beforeCreate(user, cb) {
  await BaseUser.beforeCreate(user, () => 0);
  //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **[_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith)** to check what each property being merged is and if it is a function just pick the object and not the source (in your case the `source` is `BaseUser`):

```
const BaseUser = require("../../BaseUser.js");

let obj = {
  attributes: {
    verify_key: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: async function(user, cb) {
    user.verify_key = 'helloworld'; //crypto used to generate...
    cb();
  }
}
module.exports = _.mergeWith(
  obj, 
  BaseUser, 
  (objValue, srcValue, key, object, source) => _.isFunction(objValue) ? objValue : _.merge(object[key], source[key])
)
```

Here is a test:

```js
var data = {
  food: "chicken",
  foo: () => console.log('chicken!')
}

var source = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 1,
  foo: () => console.log('foo!')
}

var result = _.merge(data, source, (objValue, srcValue, key, object, source) => _.isFunction(objValue) ? objValue : _.merge(object[key], source[key]))

console.log(result)
result.foo()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```